# List of possible information_schema.columns.data_type?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I am looking for a list of possible `information_schema.columns.data_type` values.

Is there a compiled list or way to generate one?

If there are differences based on RDBS type please provide any related information. I am interested only in MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Comment: all the supported data type of mysql can be in the list (for mysql)

Comment: You could try reading the manuals or search for mysq vs postgresql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-postgresql-typemapping.html

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks. That list does not include "timestamp without time zone".